# plotmarks are displayed as default marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
            grid=major, 
            x=5mm,
            y=5mm,
            xtick={-5,-4,...,5},     
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=5,
            xlabel={\tiny $x$},
            axis x line=middle,
            ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
            tick label style={font=\tiny},
            ymin=-10,
            ymax=10,
            ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
            axis y line=middle,
            samples=500,
            domain=-10:10,
            restrict y to domain=-20:20,
            no markers
        ]
        \addplot {x^5};
        \addplot [only marks,mark=o] coordinates { (1, 1) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Problem

Although I included *plotmarks* and set *mark=o*, the default black, filled mark is used.

- **Picture #1** shows the result of the code above.
- **Picture #2** shows the kind of mark I want to have.
- **Picture #3** shows the result of the code after removing `no markers`.
- **Picture #4** shows the result of the code after removing `no markers` *and* the plotted function graph.

1) [image]
2) [image]
3) [image]
4) [image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs I've edited my question. Should I also remove the beamer dependency?

Comment: Yes; unless the problem has to do with `beamer`, using a simpler class like `article` may be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pgfplots` manual (v1.9, p158) has this to say about the `no markers` key (thanks to percusse for the reference):

> A key which overrides any mark value set by `cycle list` of option lists after `\addplot`.
>   If this style is provided as argument to a complete `axis`, it is appended to `every axis plot post` such that it disables markers even for `cycle list`s which contain markers.

The `no markers` option is the culprit, here: it overrides the `only marks, mark=o` options in your second `\addplot`.

If you don't pass `no markers` to the `axis` environment, and use `+[mark=none]` for the plot, you get the desired output.

**Edit**: In case your wondering, the plus sign in `\addplot +[mark=none] ...` is to append the `mark=none` option to the options already implicitly used instead of overriding them. See subsubsection 4.7.7 in the `pgfplots` documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
            grid=major, 
            x=5mm,
            y=5mm,
            xtick={-5,-4,...,5},     
            xmin=-5,
            xmax=5,
            xlabel={\tiny $x$},
            axis x line=middle,
            ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
            tick label style={font=\tiny},
            ymin=-10,
            ymax=10,
            ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
            axis y line=middle,
            samples=500,
            domain=-10:10,
            restrict y to domain=-20:20,
        ]
        \addplot +[mark=none]{x^5};
        \addplot [only marks,mark=o] coordinates { (1, 1) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, your code works fine! One question though: what does the plus sign mean in front of the square bracket `+[mark=none]`?